# How to change items in cache

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello i want to change and alter values inside the cache of my acumatica cache i would like to know how to do it

for example i want to change the Ext. Cost value pro grammatically of the first line or the second line or can i check if there is already a "Data Backup" on transaction Descr.

[image]

[image]

```
 public delegate void PersistDelegate();
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
{
      if (Globalvar.GlobalBoolean == true)
        {
            PXCache cache = Base.Transactions.Cache;
        APTran red = new APTran();
        red.BranchID = Base.Transactions.Current.BranchID;
        red.InventoryID = 10045;
        var curyl = Convert.ToDecimal(Globalvar.Globalred);
        red.CuryLineAmt = curyl * -1;
        cache.Insert(red);

        }
        else
        {

        }

         baseMethod();
}
```

this code add a new line on persist but if it save again it add the same line agaub u wabt ti check if there is already a inventoryID =10045; in the cache

thank you for your help

Comment: I don't know this system, but when you have a cache, you can also read items *from* it. So you need to explicitly check whether your record is already stored, and act accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your cache instance by using a view name or cache type. Ex: *(Where 'Base' is the graph instance)*

```
Base.Transactions.Cache
```

or

```
Base.Caches<APTran>().Cache
```

Using the cache instance you can loop the cached values using `Cached`, `Inserted`, `Updated`, or `Deleted` depending on which type of record you are looking for. You can also use `GetStatus()` on an object to find out if its inserted, updated, etc. Alternatively calling `PXSelect` will find the results in cache (`PXSelectReadOnly` will not).

So you could loop your results like so:

```
foreach (MyDac row in Base.Caches<MyDac>().Cache.Cached)
{
    // logic
}
```

If you know the key values of the cache object you are looking for you can use Locate to find by key fields:

```
var row = (MyDac)Base.Transactions.Cache.Locate(new MyDac
{
    MyKey1 = "",
    MyKey2 = ""
    // etc... must include each key field
});
```

As Mentioned before you can also just use a `PXSelect` statement to get the values.

Once you have the row to update the values you set the object properties and then call your cache `Update(row)` before the base persist and you are good to go. Similar if needing to `Insert(row)` or `Delete(row)`.

So in your case you might end up with something like this in your persist:

```
foreach (APTran row in Base.Transactions.Cache.Cached)
{
    if (Globalvar.GlobalBoolean != true || row.TranDesc == null || !row.TranDesc.Contains("Data Backup"))
    {
        continue;
    }

    //Found my row
    var curyl = Convert.ToDecimal(Globalvar.Globalred);
    row.CuryLineAmt = curyl * -1;
    Base.Transactions.Update(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a Detailed answer brendan really appreciate it helped me alot for this customization and also the next